# Ext js Store handle failed responses

Tags: extjs, store, sencha-architect

I snyc my Ext JS store in multiple places and I'm looking for a way to handle the responses in one place.

Is there a way,event or a technique to achieve this?
I have tried the `load` event but it is not triggered by the `sync` method. I have also tried the `metachange` event of the store proxy.

Instead of calling the failure function every time a store sync is done I would like to have this in united place.

Answer (score 4):

In 4.2, you can use overrides to do this. If I remember correctly, I overrode the `exception` listener in `Ext.data.proxy.Ajax` once.

```
Ext.define('App.Ajax.Override', {
    override: 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
    listeners: {
        exception: function (proxy, response, operation, eOpts) {
            //....
        }
    }
});
```

And for the successful request, perhaps the `load` listener of the store. I'm sorry I don't have access to the working code anymore but that should guide you a bit.

Comment: Yes this could be the correct method. Will give it a try.